# Why cast is needed when returning this from self-bound generic in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

In this case my IDE shows compilation error in return statement.

```
public class Base<T extends Base>{
    public T get(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

When I add a typecast as in code bellow everything works fine, however I don't get why typecast is needed.

```
public class Base<T extends Base>{
    public T get(){
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

Doesn't Java replace all bounded generic occurrences with bounded type? Can someone explain what is going on under the hood and why typecast is needed?

**Edit 1.**

Thanks to Lothars and algrid answers it is now clear that this standalone case can cause `ClassCastException`. This is not safe so `Base` should probably be abstract.

The intent of this is to create a base class for Builder classes so that extended methods would return the type of the extending class. This is needed for method chaining. In the example bellow the return type of `child.setParamOne(1)` will be `Child` despite the fact that it is defined above in the inheritance hierarchy.

Is this code safe? Do you have any suggestions or alternatives for approaching this problem?

```
public abstract class Base<T extends Base>{
    int paramOne;

    public T setParamOne(int param){
        this.paramOne = param;
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public final class Child extends Base<Child> {
    int paramTwo;

    public Child setParamTwo(int param){
        this.paramTwo = param;
        return this;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child()
                .setParamOne(1)
                .setParamTwo(1);
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't Java replace all bounded generic occurrences with bounded type?" - are you talking about erasure? Erasure limits what can be checked at runtime, but it doesn't prevent type-safety checks at compile time.

Comment: `this` might not actually be a `T`, such as `new Base<ChildOfBase>().get();`

Comment: That is some convoluted code here; what is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: @fge I updated the question so the context is more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: "Is this code safe?" No, it is not safe. Consider you have a `class Foo extends Base<Child>` and then the following will compile: `new Foo().setParamOne(1).setParamTwo(1)` but it will cause an exception at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that your `this` is of the type `T`? It's of the type `Base<T>`.

Try to run the following code and you'll get `ClassCastException`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base<Child> b = new Base<>();
        // b.get() returns an instance of Base, not Child (however it's mistakenly cast to Child)
        Child1 c = b.get();
    }

    public static class Base<T extends Base>{
        public T get(){
            return (T) this;
        }
    }

    public static class Child extends Base {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is the same as the error being created for code like this:

```
public void myMethod(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = is;
}
```

Just with generics. To get rid of the complier error you can do the cast as you did in your code:

```
public void myMethod(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = (ByteArrayInputStream) is;
}
```

But this will fail during runtime if the passed inputstream is not a `ByteArrayInputStream` or a class derived from it. The same will happen with your code. Unless you only create instances of `Base<Base>` the cast will lead to an error when calling `get`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
public class Base<T extends Base>{
    public T get(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

the return statement is incorrect, because `this` is an instance of `Base<T>` and not `T`.

If your aim is to return the instance itself (by the way, I'm not sure why you would be doing this), the code should look like this:

```
public class Base<T extends Base>{
    public Base<T> get(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

If your aim is to return the parameterized type, then you will probably not be able to do that. The parameterized type itself is *not* an instance within the `Base` class, but, again, just the parameterized type. If that is what you need, you can get the parameterized type class using reflection.

Comment: The aim is to return the object of parameter type. I updated the question. You can read why this is needed.

Comment: Ok, got it. I am not sure why you would need to use generics in that case. IMHO, I see a very simple class model using `Base` as the base class and no need to use generics for the purpose you explained. `this` will always be the implemented class, which is both `Base` and its subclass.

Comment: The reason is that without Generic when I call inherited Base methods on a Child as In 'static void main' the return type will be Base and I won't be able to chain methods that are implemented in Child without a cast somewhere outside.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is unsafe because `this` (which has type `Base<T>`) may not be a `T`. We only know that `T` is a `Base`, but not the other way around.

There is no way to represent a "self type" in Java. So what you want to do is impossible. Instead, you can make an abstract method that forces implementing subclasses to provide a way to return a `T`:

```
public class Base<T> {
    public abstract T get();
}

public final class Child extends Base<Child> {
    public Child get() {
        return this;
    }
}
```